# Hosting WCF service in Windows service

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, wcf

There is a client in the form of an ASP.NET MVC application, there is a WCF service, requests to the WCF service are sent from the client, the service itself manipulates database data through the Entity Framework. Everything works locally in the Visual Studio development environment via IIS Express, but when I deploy this service on a Windows service, an error appears

> "The underlying provider failed on Open."

DB connection string in app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AddressBookEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/ContactModel.csdl|res://*/ContactModel.ssdl|res://*/ContactModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\AddressBook.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use SQL Server Express, attached filename requires a particular user context

Comment: Yes.  You seem to be using the LocalDb flavor of SQL Express, which is installed with Visual Studio.  On a server you should use the Windows Service flavor of SQL Express, and permanently mount your database on the server.